# C# Compare values in SPItemList and only retrieve matching ones

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, sharepoint

My current statement retrieves all `Header1Ref` values from SharePoint `SPListItem`

Instead of retrieving all, I would like to filter based on matching results from an array.

May I know how can it be done?

**Current statement:**

```
SPView view = record.GetView(ErmsConfig.GetGuid(ErmsConfig.Config.RecordListView));

SPQuery query = new SPQuery(view)                     
{
    RowLimit = 0,                     
};

SPListItemCollection primaryHeaders = record.GetItems(query);

//currently gets all Header1Ref 
//- include filter to display only matches with parametersList[]
var distinctPrimaryHeaders = (from SPListItem item1 in primaryHeaders select item1["Header1Ref"]).Distinct().ToList();
```

**Array to compare with:**

```
//contain Header1Ref value in each cell to retrieve
parametersList[]
```

Comment: I don't know much about sharepoint developpement but you can use where clause in linq statement right? have you tried something yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sample code for your reference(I set Header1Ref as text field for testing), hope it helps you.

```
var filterItems = primaryHeaders.Cast<SPListItem>()
                                .Where(p => p["Header1Ref"].ToString() == "a");
                foreach(var item in filterItems)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(item.Title);
                }
```